# how to integrate angularjs with CSOM to connect sharepoint site

Tags: c#, angularjs, sharepoint

I am creating an application which is having user login module.for that I am using asp.net webforms(aspx pages). after login user can add see list of tools added into the system and can add,edit tools. for those pages I want to use angularjs but problem is that when user add a tool it need to submit in a share point website by using CSOM. so is this possible to use angularjs for two or three pages with remaining in asp.net web forms

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SharePoint 2010/2013, you can just use the REST services within your angular page to call the different methods of a list to add/edit/delete/view an item.